# Reycle Bitmaps in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, recycle

I am using google map view and adding markers to it using this code:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(chargingStationObject.geoData)
.title(chargingStationObject.name)
.snippet(chargingStationObject.stationAvailability)
.data((chargingStationObject.id))
.icon(iconDescriptor));
```

iconDescriptor is created like this:

```
iconDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getResources()
     .getIdentifier("mapicon", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName()));
```

When there are too many markers on my map, the heap is filled to its maximum, and after a while the app crashed with an out-of-memory-exception. This only happens when there are or have been a larger amount of markers on the map. Even after I call .clear(), the heap is still rather large.

Maybe the bitmaps haven't been recycled properly?

Comment: have you know about clustering ?

Comment: is this code inside loop?

Comment: @Haresh Yes, but I have reasons not to use clustering.

Comment: @Biraj Zalavadia Yes, it's inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Do on thing.

I assume, you are using same marker for all location.

Put the condition here

```
if(iconDescriptor==null){
            iconDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getResources().getIdentifier("mapicon", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName()));
        }
```

Do not create new bitmap for every marker use just one copy for that and see what happens.

Comment: iconDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory... is only called once at onCreate(), I already thought of that :)

Comment: Then you must use clustering for that.

Comment: Ok, but shouldn't it be possible to recycle those used Bitmaps once they are no longer shown on the map (I'm not sure that they are recycled, that's why I would like to initiate that process myself)

Answer (score 0):

for handle larger amount of markers on google map have to use Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility

For find more visit,
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: As I said, I have my reasons why I am not clustering my markers :)